# How to convert 1 row in a SQL SELECT Statement to INT

Tags: sql, string, integer

I have a SELECT statement where I am selecting multiple rows from a table, all but one of these rows are a STRING value, the other is an INT.  I want to be able to read the row that contains an Integer number, and convert just that row to an Int, so I can use it to compare against other INT values on screen.

If I try to compare it now, it removes the trailing 0's as it is reading it as a String, so it thinks '12' is bigger than '40', as it's reading '12'(The on screen value) and '4'(From the table) removing the 0's.

I am using Java to grab a value on screen, this works fine, it converts it to INT, and is displaying properly, so I now need to convert the 'age' column to an INT so I can compare it to the value on screen, without the SQL value removing the 0's at the end, as it currently reads it as a String.

My SELECT statement below:

```
SELECT name, age, city, department
FROM myTable

WHERE age >= '"+valueOnScreen+"'
```

IF age = 25, and valueOnScreen = 20, it will work fine, as it sees it as 25, and 20.

IF age = 20, and valueOnScreen = 5, it will not work, as it sees it as 2, and 5

I have tried:

```
DECLARE @AGE INT
SELECT name, @AGE = age, city, department
FROM myTable

WHERE age >= '"+valueOnScreen+"'
```

I get error: 'A SELECT statement that assigns a value to a variable must not be combined with data-retrieval operations.; nested exception is com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: A SELECT statement that assigns a value to a variable must not be combined with data-retrieval operations'

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: I think you are confused by the difference between "rows" and "columns", which makes the question hard to follow.  Also tag with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks like SQL Server.  You should be constructing the query to take a *parameter*.  The query would look something like:

```
SELECT name, age, city, department
FROM myTable
WHERE age >= ?;
```

Then you would pass in an *integer* parameter for the comparison.  That is the right way to accomplish what you are trying to do.

Note:  This answer doesn't actually depend on the underlying databases.  Parameters are always the right way to pass in user-provided constant values.